# issue with JcomboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

well i'm trying to test on a jcomboBox something like this:
if the default value of the comboBox == "something" (like before i even make a choice) i will have an error message telling me i forgot to click on it!!
it's that "something" that i don't know. 
you may have some other idea or way of doing the test!!
anyway with what i've come out with, in java this is how you write it:

```
if(mycoomboBomx.getselectedIndex() == someValue )
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you haven't made a choice yet!!");
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex()

> Returns:
>     an integer specifying the currently selected list item, where 0 specifies the first item in the list; or -1 if no item is selected or if the currently selected item is not in the list

oh, the joy of reading...

Comment: no hahaha :D i tried that with -1 but still didn't work! anyway now i am sure that it's -1 when you don't select nothing thank you anyway

Comment: thank you for your concern i've found another way to see if the user chose or not :D